# What's the way to show file tree on template using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this which I the server gives to the template:

```
test_data/reads_1.fq

test_data/reads_2.fq

test_data/test_ref.bt2

test_data/test_ref.ebwt

test_data/test_ref.fa

test_data/test_ref2.bt2

test_data/new_directory/ok.txt
```

I want to show these files in a tree view like this:

```
test_data
   reads_1.fq
   reads_1.fq
   test_ref.bt2
   test_ref.ebwt
   test_ref.ebwt

   new_directory
       ok.txt
```

What's the best possible way to do like this? Thanks

**Edit**

I am sending my data like this as a list(Python):

```
['test_data/reads1.fq', 'test_data/reads_2.fq', test_data/new_directory/ok.txt]
```

**Edit2**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            var string=["test_data/new_directory/ok.txt","test_data/reads_1.fq","test_data/test_ref.fa"];

            for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
            var result = string[i].split('/');
              $('html').html('<ul><li>'+result[0]+'</li><ul><li>'+result[1]+'</li><ul><li>'+result[2]+'</li></ul></ul>');
            }
            });
```

**Result**

```
test_data
   test_ref.fa
       undefined
```

**Expected Result:**

```
test_data
    reads_1.fq
    reads_2.fq

    new_directory
        ok.txt
```

Comment: You should search for "jQuery tree", there are some plugins you can use

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var string=["test_data/new_directory/ok.txt","test_data/reads_1.fq","test_data/test_ref.fa"];

                 for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){

                     var result = string[i].split('/');
                     console.log(result);
                 }
});
</script>
```

it may not be the best practice, but you need something like this. You also may put your string into array to check whether indexes are the same to avoid the repetition. If I ave time I will look into this properly.

Comment: How can I make the dynamic data sit the way you show? There can be numerous sub-directories. Also, I don't want to show undefined when there's no file. Please see my updated question.

Comment: run the console and you'll see it then just loop the indexes to display that in the list

Comment: seems like this plugin will help you http://www.jstree.com/demo otherwise you may spend hours on it

Comment: I don't want onlick event, tree structure with bold and other stuffs. I don't want to show the list that way.